# Type 'List<Widget>' is not a subtype of type 'Widget'

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have looked for similar answers and tried using their proposed solutions with no success. I am trying to build a ListView with data from the Firestore. Everytime I try to run it, it gives me a "Type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'Widget'".

Thank you in advance!

Here are the two blocks of code involved in the error:

```
class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: Firestore.instance.collection("exercises").snapshots(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) return new Text("There is no expense");
          return new Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.blue[100],
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('Test'),
              backgroundColor: Colors.blue[400],
              elevation: 0.0,
            ),
            body: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                ListView(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                  children: <Widget>[getExpenseItems(snapshot)]
                )
              ],
            ),
          );
        });
  }


getExpenseItems(AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
    return snapshot.data.documents.map<Widget>((doc) =>
      new Container(
        child: Card(
          child: ListTile(
              title: new Text(doc["nome"]),
              subtitle: new Text(doc["link"])
          ),
        ),
      )
    ).toList();
  }
```

Comment: replace <Widget>[getExpenseItems(snapshot)] with getExpenseItems(snapshot)

Comment: I swear I tried multiple times to remove and add <Widget> from here and there. Can't believe I did not try removing that one. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spread the returned list of widgets from `getExpenseItems(snapshot)`:

```dart
body: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                ListView(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                  children: <Widget>[...getExpenseItems(snapshot)]
                )
              ],
            ),
//....
```

Comment: Much appreciated! I tried to add and remove <Widget> from multiple places but I guess I did not try that one.~

Comment: Glad it helped. I have not added a detailed explanation as it seems a very trivial question. I hope you got the reasoning behind the use of spread operation on ```getExpenseItems(snapshot)```